# Getting NullPointerException when trying to map with ModelMapper with Java EE8

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-11, modelmapper

I'm trying to get my head around ModelMapper, followed the documentation and [this](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.modelmapper.ModelMapper/addMappings) tutorial.

Everytime I test this with a request, I get an EJB Exception caused by NullPointerException.

When I deploy the application on Wildfly18, I see that the Bean is loaded and registered.
I'm using OpenJDK 11 for the project.

The model looks like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentModel {

    @Inject
    private StudentMapper studentMapper;

    private Long id;
    private String forename;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;

    public StudentModel toModel(Student student) {
       StudentModel studentModel = studentMapper.toModel(student);
       return studentModel;
    }
}
```

Mapper class:

```
@Local
@Stateless
public class StudentMapper{

    private ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    public StudentMapper() {
        modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Student, StudentModel>() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                skip().setId(null);
                map().setEmail(source.getEmail());
                map().setForename(source.getForename());
                map().setLastname(source.getLastname());
            }
        });
    }

    public StudentModel toModel(Student student) {
        return modelMapper.map(student, StudentModel.class);
    }
}
```

Anyone have some idea what I am missing on this?

EDIT. Stacktrace and invoking classes:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:203)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInImportedTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:174)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:360)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.10.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:627)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:266)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:492)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:507)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:70)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:507)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:507)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:507)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:205)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:507)
        at org.wildfly.common@1.5.1.Final//org.wildfly.common.context.Contextual.runExConsumer(Contextual.java:203)
        at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.23.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequestInitial(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:334)
       at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:362)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.10.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:627)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
        at deployment.school.war//se.alten.schoolproject.rest.StudentController$$$view5.addStudent(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:317)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at deployment.school.war//se.alten.schoolproject.model.StudentModel.toModel(StudentModel.java:31)
        at deployment.school.war//se.alten.schoolproject.dao.SchoolDataAccess.addStudent(SchoolDataAccess.java:37)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.common@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:185)
```

Happens when I run the response from my transaction has be run. If I comment out the model layer and return the entity it works perfectly.

```
   public StudentModel addStudent(String newStudent) throws DuplicateEmailException, IncompleteFormException {
        Student studentToAdd = student.toEntity(newStudent);

        studentTransactionAccess.addStudent(studentToAdd);
        return studentModel.toModel(studentToAdd);
       //return studentToAdd;

    }
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace; the code invoking the code above will probably be helpful too.

Comment: All this only shows that `studentToAdd` is null, for some reason. You'll need to determine why `studentToAdd` comes back null from your `toEntity` call